# Find the number of regular files and directories in current directory and sub-directories INCLUDING current directory

Tags: linux, unix, directory, find, wc

Question is in the title,

Obviously I know that what I am asking in just equal to:
1 + 
find . -type f | wc -l

So my question is how you can combine both ?

Many thanks in advance !!

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Your question says "Find the number of regular files and directories", so using only `-type f` is not correct as it will find only regular files, not directories. You need to find both types: `-type f -o -type d`.

Another detail. `find` will also find the current directory and it will display it as the first result, so you don't need to do `+1`. It's already included!

Also use `-prune` to skip files and directories starting with `.` (hidden). In this case `-o print` is necessary. And since we don't want files or directories starting with `.`, we cannot use `.` as the search path, otherwise we will skip everything since all results will start with `.`. Use `$PWD` instead.

```
find $PWD \( -type f -or -type d \) -name ".*" -prune -o -print | wc -l
```

Note that this will exclude all files and directories included into hidden directories, even if those ones are not hidden. For instance, a file like this one will be exluded:

```
/my/path/.hidden_dir/not_hidden_file
```

Comment: When you use `-o` you need to use `-print` in each branch

Comment: I thought that default was disabled when `-o` is used, but I was wrong.

Comment: Thx a lot Vicente but I tried this only and it was counting a hidden file (.cg_conf) as well ?